# Heading : date text inside date field not aligned to left only on IOS 15 and higher for lightning text date type aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, css

I am using the following css class on my lightning-input type date field on my **aura component**

css:

```
    .THIS.test{
-webkit-appearance : none !important;
text-align :left !important;}
```

cmp:

```
<lightning:input class="test" type="date"</lightning:input>
```

It is working fine on every place except IOS 15 and onward, where the date text is centre aligned instead of left.

I tried the following after checking on google for some answers :

```
.THIS.test{
-webkit-appearance : none !important;
text-align :left !important;}
```

But this did not work.I also tried using the below statement into the css file, but it seems its not supported on aura.

```
input::-webkit-date-and-time-value{ text-align:left; }
```

Can anyone suggest what I can use in this case?[image]

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested but getting the same error again .Please suggest some ways to sort it out .

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to give space between the .THIS and your custom class. Try the below:

```
.THIS .test{
text-align :left !important;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the same way you suggested but getting the same error again .Please suggest some ways to sort it out .